# Getting user input using tkinters Entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

So the code I have posted below returns this error:

```
bound method StringVar.get of tkinter.StringVar object at 0x03E15410
```

i did have to take out the brackets ^

and please don't mind the indenting or other small details. I cut out a lot of extra irreverent code.

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="I have no idea what I'm doing!")
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        global url
        url = StringVar()

        urlbox = ttk.Entry(controller, textvariable=url)
        urlbox.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        label2 = ttk.Label(self, text="Press button to start")
        label2.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Start!",
                            command=self.vgrab)
        button1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

    def vgrab(self):
        print(url.get)
```

I'd also like to add, I've been learning python for about a week now. So I'm very much so still a beginner.

Comment: `print(url.get)` should be `print(url.get())`. You need to call the function. It's not an error, what you are printing is a representation of the function itself. Without a complete, runnable example it's difficult to say that with that change your code would then run without issue.

Comment: That actually made it work, I've been workin at this for over 24 hours. But, I actually deleted the () while messing around trying to get it to work. so it seems like a bunch of things i have done made it work, but since I forgot to add the () back, it broke it even more so. Wonderful xD. Thank you so much for pointing it out to me!